# Return any matching text from another column

Tags: excel

I'm trying to ask to Excel to return any text from one column that matches the text from another column (not just a "yes" or "no").

For example: Cell A1 contains "Dog" Cell B1 contains "Dog Bird Cat" I would like Excel to give me the words from B1 that match A1 (Dog) in cell C1 and the words from B1 that do not match A1 (Bird Cat) in cell D1.

I have a lot of rows-- so I need a formula that can return the actual words that match/do not match and can be applied to many rows at once.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Can the Dog Cat Bird entries be stored in a line of adjacent cells?  If so, MATCH will do the job.

Comment: I haven't tried anything on my own-- I'm really new to excel, so I'm not sure where to start. Yes, I can put them in adjacent cells. I'll give MATCH a try. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

in C1: `=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(A1,B1)>0,A1),"")`
in D1: `=IFERROR(TRIM(IF(SEARCH(A1,B1)>0,SUBSTITUTE(B1,A1,""),"")),"")`

copied down to suit.